# How to remove page name using .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL like:

```
http://www.example.com/list/css/Introduction-of-CSS
```

But I want to remove the  `/list/` in between so finally it would look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/css/Introduction-of-CSS
```

My `.htaccess` currently has this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule list/(.*)/(.*)/ list.php?catid=$1&tid=$2
RewriteRule list/(.*)/(.*) list.php?catid=$1&tid=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/css/([\w-]+)/?$ $1/list.php?catid=$2&tid=$3 [L]
```

If any issue comment below..